# For each loop, compare to next item on the list

Tags: vb.net

I am writing an application where I bring change history of items from the database and place them on the table using For Each loop. I would, however, like to show in table what information has changed in each edit. Is it possible to compare variables of each item to the variables of next loop in For Each loop?

Something like:

```
For Each k As Examplemodel In Model

  'Find next item on the loop after current one somehow
   Dim nextItem = Model.Item(k+1) 'something like this

  If k.ItemsName <> nextItem.Itemsname 'if the name has changed in edit
    'show result in bold
  Else
     'show result in normal font weight
  End If

 Next
```

Is this possible and if not, what's the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Not in a for each loop. if `Model` have indexers you can change your for each loop to a for loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do it in a foreach loop directly.
If your `Model` class have indexers you can easily convert it into a for loop:

```
If Model.Count > 1 Then
    For i as Integer = 0 to Model.Count - 2 ' Note the -2 here !!!
        Dim Item As Examplemodel = Model(i)
        Dim NextItem As Examplemodel = Model(i + 1)

        if Item.ItemsName <> NextItem.ItemsName then
            'show result in bold
        else
            'show result in normal font weight
        end if
    Next
    'show result of NextItem here, since the last item doesn't get shown in the loop
Else
    'show result of only item here
End If
```

If not, you can use a workaround like this:

```
Dim PrevItem as Examplemodel = Nothing ' Assuming a reference type

For Each k As Examplemodel In Model

    If Not IsNothing(PrevItem) AndAlso k.ItemsName <> Prev.Itemsname 'if the name has changed in edit
        'show result (of PrevItem!!!) in bold
    Else
        'show result (of PrevItem!!!) in normal font weight
    End If
    PrevItem = k
Next

'show result (of PrevItem (currently the last item in Model) in normal font weight
```

Comment: Why -2? It will work with -1. I think -2 might make it fail on the first iteration if there is only one item. I think it should check if i = Model.count - 1 to skip the last one if this is what was intended. It could even compare the last one to the first one because that might also make sense.

Comment: @JohnnyPrescott -2 because indexes are zero based, meaning the length of the array or the count of the list is the last index + 1. Since I've used `i+1` inside the loop, it must be -2 and not -1. However, there is a problem in my first code - it will not show the last item. easy fix - just show it after the loop. edited my answer. to reflect that.

Comment: -1 is for a standard loop, which is what I would do. Then compare with i+1 like you did. Check when you get to the last iteration and compare with index 0 to compare last and first. Both works but I think its more elegant that way. Also, if model.count = 1, it will fail because the loop end at a negative, or do nothing cause I never tested that in the past but I assume it is not valid. I miht be wrong on that point though.

Comment: @JohnnyPrescott you are correct if model.count = 1 it will fail. but using a standard loop with count-1 means to add another condition inside the loop, while looping to count-2 means you need to add a condition outside the loop. Both solutions are valid, it's a matter of coding style.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a normal for loop:

```
Dim numbers() As Integer = New Integer() {1, 2, 4, 8}

Sub Main()
    For index As Integer = 0 To numbers.Length - 2
        Dim currentInt As Integer = numbers(index)
        Dim nextInt As Integer = numbers(index + 1)
        Console.WriteLine(currentInt)
        Console.WriteLine(nextInt)
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Last iteration will fail without -1 in your loop

Answer (score 0):

Another approach to use LINQ `Aggregate` extension method, which use first item of collection as initial value. So every item will have access to previous one.

```
Public Class ItemChanges
    Public Property Item As ExampleModel
    Public Property Changes As New Hash(Of String)
End Class

Public Function Check(previous As ItemChanges, current As ItemChanges) As ItemChanges
    If current.Item.Name <> previous.Item.Name Then 
        current.Changes.Add(Nameof(current.Name))
    End
    Return current
End Function

' assume model is collection of items
Dim itemWithChanges = 
    model.Select(Function(m) New ItemChanges With { .Item = m })
         .Aggregate(AddressOf(Check))
         .ToList()
```

Then you can use calculated result as you want - every item will have a hash of property names which had changed

```
If checkedItem.Changes.Contains(Nameof(checkedItem.Item.Name)) Then
    ' use bold font or different color
End
```